# Prove that Steenrod squares are stable

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, cohomology-operations

I have been studying the mod 2 Steenrod algebra. And I try to solve some exercises of it.

Can you help me to check this proof:

> Let $SX$ denote the suspension of $X$, and let $S: \underline{H}^q(X) \rightarrow \underline{H}^{q+1}(SX)$ denote the suspension isomorphism. Then, from the property:
>
> > If $\delta: H^q(A) \rightarrow H^{q+1}(X,A)$ is the coboundary map, then $\delta \operatorname{Sq}^i = \operatorname{Sq}^i \delta$
>
> Prove that $s \operatorname{Sq}^i = \operatorname{Sq}^i s$.

Proof:
Let $CX$ and $C'X$ be two cones on $X$. Then $SX = CX \cup C'X$, where $CX \cap C'X =X$. The suspension isomorphism is defined by the following commutative diagram of reduced cohomology groups

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\underline{H}^q(X) @>s>> \underline{H}^{q+1}(SX) \\
@V{\cong}VV & @A{\cong}AA \\
\underline{H}^{q+1}(CX,X) @>{excisio}>> \underline{H}^{q+1}(SX,C'X)
\end{CD}$$

Then, $s: \underline{H}^q(X) \rightarrow \underline{H}^{q+1}(CX,X) \cong \underline{H}^{q+1}(SX)$, It is easy to check that $s$ is a coboundary map. So by applying to the property, the statement is proved.

I am not sure about the last argument. Can you help me to check that?

Answer (score 2):

That's not quite right. $s$ itself isn't directly a coboundary map. However you know that cohomology operations are natural maps, so they also commute with maps of the form $f^* : H^i(X,A) \to H^i(Y,B)$ where $f : (Y,B) \to (X,A)$ is a map of pairs. So $\operatorname{Sq}^i$ commutes with:

- the coboundary map $H^q(X) \to H^{q+1}(CX,X)$;
- $H^{q+1}(SX,C'X) \to H^{q+1}(CX, X)$ induced by the inclusion $(CX,X) \subset (SX, C'X)$; by excision this is an isomorphism so you can invert it, and if $\operatorname{Sq}^i f = f \operatorname{Sq}^i$ then $f^{-1} \operatorname{Sq}^i = \operatorname{Sq}^i f^{-1}$;
- $H^{q+1}(SX,C'X) \to H^{q+1}(SX)$ induced by the inclusion $(SX, \varnothing) \subset (SX, C'X)$;

so $\operatorname{Sq}^i$ commutes with the composite of all three maps, that is $s : H^q(X) \to H^{q+1}(SX)$.